# Is there a way to delete multiple files efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As stated in the title, is there a better way to delete multiple files in python? Currently, I am deleting by looping through each files.

```
import os
files = ["test_file.txt", "test_failed.txt"]
for file in files:
    if os.path.exists(file):
        os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Seems pretty efficient to me.

Comment: Loop through each file is O(n) which is pretty efficient. I don't know how do you judge the efficiency. If you have tons of files that this code will take hours, then you should consider to use some lower level language instead of python I think.

Comment: It's not really about being `O(n)`. It's that each iteration of the loop will take time. One obvious thing is to get rid of the `if`. It will reduce one `stat` call per iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's put this in perspective.

We start by disassembling the `for`-loop into bytecode using the `dis` module:

```
In [23]: dis.dis('for f in files: os.remove(f)')
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              22 (to 24)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (files)
              4 GET_ITER
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                14 (to 22)
              8 STORE_NAME               1 (f)
             10 LOAD_NAME                2 (os)
             12 LOAD_METHOD              3 (remove)
             14 LOAD_NAME                1 (f)
             16 CALL_METHOD              1
             18 POP_TOP
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   22 POP_BLOCK
        >>   24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

The only real "inefficency" here (and a small one at that) is the repeated name lookup for `os.remove`. So let's get rid of that by creating a local alias for that first.

```
In [24]: rm = os.remove
Out[24]: <function posix.remove(path, *, dir_fd=None)>

In [25]: dis.dis('for f in files: rm(f)')
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 22)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (files)
              4 GET_ITER
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                12 (to 20)
              8 STORE_NAME               1 (f)
             10 LOAD_NAME                2 (rm)
             12 LOAD_NAME                1 (f)
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 POP_TOP
             18 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   20 POP_BLOCK
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

This saves *one bytecode instruction* (`LOAD_METHOD`) per file. :-/

Generally, list comprehensions *can* be faster than `for`-loops. But when I tried both using list of 10 empty but existing files:

```
In [15]: %timeit -n1 -r1 for f in files: os.remove(f)
71.3 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

compared with a list comprehension using a local alias

```
In [32]: %timeit -n1 -r1 [rm(f) for f in files]
71 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

there is *practically* no difference.

Measuring on a recent UNIX system (FreeBSD 12, UFS filesystem on a HDD, using `%timeit` in IPython);

- `os.path.exists()` takes around 2 µs per file in a loop.
- `os.remove()` takes around 7-10 µs per file in a loop.

Using `os.stat` directly instead of via `exists` does not make much of a difference. 
And `os.remove` uses the `remove(3)` C library call. So most of its time is spent in file system operations, which are inherently *really slow* compared to a modern CPU.

So apart from writing this in C, using system calls (not C library functions) directly, there is probably not much to be gained.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing particularly inefficient about what you're doing.

However if you want to delete an entire directory, you can use rmtree.

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('/my-dir/')
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who see this thread and are looking for syntactic efficiency in deleting all files of a particular type, the following may be useful:

```
import glob, os
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"): os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are not many ways to speed this up. The final deletion of the file will have to be done (atleast on Linux which is what I'm guessing your OS is based on the filenames) using the `unlink(2)` system call that can only delete one file at a time. I imagine the file system does some kind of trickery to give you a kind of parallelism so it might be possible to get some speed boost by using multiple processes. Here are a few other suggestions.

1. Lose the `if os.path.exists`. This will run a `stat(2)` to check if the file exists and it will add a fixed amount of time to every iteration of the loop. Best to just go ahead and delete it and if the file doesn't exist, catch the exception, ignore it and move on (forgiveness rather than permission).
2. If all these files are in a directory, it might make sense to just call something (maybe even shell out) to delete the entire directory. You should measure this though.
3. How are going to get the list of files? That will be time consuming as well. If it's going to be read from a file or generated, you should consider that in your optimisation as well.

Comment: Would a `try..catch` really be faster than `os.path.exists`?

Comment: Yup. For 2 reasons that I can think of. 1. If most of the files are there, then there will not be any overhead for those. With the `exists` call, there will be an overhead for every file. 2. If we go multi threaded, there might be race conditions with the `exists` call which can cause the program to crash.

Comment: Yeah I guess the exception will only be raised sometimes when the file doesn't exist, and the `exists()` will run every time, which is unnecessary. That's actually a great point. I'll upvote this answer in the morning :)